# Sharepoint 2013:I Cannot access host site

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

Sharepoint 2013:I want to iterate through all the lists present in mu sharepoint online site. However when I a loading the host side and calling the executeQueryAsync function, it always seems to call the faliure function, i.e I get an alert "in failure" as the output

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser(); 
var hostUrl
var hostContext
var site
(function () {

// This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object    which is 
    // needed to use the SharePoint object model
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#Add_List').click(function(event)
        {
        //  alert("in Add_List ")
   hostUrl=decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
        alert("host URL:"+hostUrl);

        hostContext=new SP.AppContextSite(context,hostUrl)
        site=hostContext.get_web();
        context.load(site)
        context.executeQueryAsync(success,failure)

    })
  });


})();

function getQueryStringParameter(param)
{
 var params=document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&")
//alert(""+params);
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
     var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
     alert(""+singleParam[i])
     if (singleParam[0] == param) {
         alert("if")
         return singleParam[1];

     }
 }
}
function success()
{
 alert("in success")
} 
function failure()
 {
alert("in failure")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the cross-site library **ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory** and the app manifest must request the read permission for the host web.

For the code you can use the library this way:

```
context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
context.load(this.web);
```

For the request you must include this permission on the manifest

```
<AppPermissionRequests>
  <AppPermissionRequest 
    Scope="http://sharepoint/" 
    Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

You can find more infos (and above examples) on [MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx)